# find the line no from the give string

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

i want to get the line no from the below string. i tried the following to get line no but doesn't look reliable

`string.split('Line')[1].split(':')[0]`

**String:**

`"Line 30:6 Table not found 'users'"`

**output:**

`{
line: 30,
statement: "Table not found 'users'"
}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = "Line 30:6 Table not found 'users'";
y = x.split(":");

var newObj = {
  line : y[0].split(" ")[1],
  data : y[1].substr(2)
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) for extracting data from a string.

**Example: The extract() function below will do the job**

```
var regex =  /^Line ([0-9]+):[0-9]+ (.*)$/g

function extract(str){
    var result = regex.exec(str);
    if(result != null){
        return {
            "line": result[1],
            "data": result[2]
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}


var input = "Line 30:6 Table not found 'users'";
var output = extract(input);
```